# JQuery fadeOut(function(){fadeIn});

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a problem with my webpage.
I have 4 div's which should all fade in after the one before fades out. The code I use is:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#box3').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#box4').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

With #box1 > #box2 it works, with #box2 > #box3 it works but when I try to go from #box3 > #box4 sometimes #box3 fades out then fades in with #box4. I have No idea why it is doing this.

Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/chLRa/4/ now working. Sometimes when going from 3 to 4 it still fades in 3 and 4

Comment: Show some HTML or put it in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: There might be something wrong with those elements so putting your code in jsfiddle would be a help

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work, which doesn't help in explaining what you're trying to do, or what the expected outcome should look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple helper function to help you do this.

```
function fade(thisIn, callback){
    boxes.not(thisIn).filter(':visible').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        thisIn.fadeIn('slow', callback);
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzul1983/TYqk4/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I'd say try using [finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) method:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#box3').finish().delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#box4').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Maybe would be better in your case to use it after delay()

Comment: finish method has been added from 1.9 stop(true,true) can be used in previous versions

Comment: @KevinB same, but i don't really get the difference with stop. Is it the same thing?

Comment: .finish() also causes the CSS property of all queued animations to jump to their end values, as well.http://api.jquery.com/finish/

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, now the delay doesn't work on #box4 and #box3 still fades in after the delay.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using the callback version of those methods:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('#box1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#box2').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $('#box2').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#box3').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    $('#box3').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $('#box4').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                            $('#box4').fadeOut('slow');
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/vDxzL/1/)

Comment: I have made it so that every box has a separate button to fadeout itself and fadein the next one. This way they all fadeOut fadeIn with only one button

Comment: My solution only has one button, as well. Did you look at my fiddle?

Comment: My site has 1 button every box, total 4 buttons. Every button fades in another div. I have updated my fiddle with a working example

Answer (score 0):

jQuery official documentation says, that second param is not a callback, but easing style.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#fadeIn-duration-easing-complete
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-easing-complete

```
$('#el').fadeOut(750,'swing',function(){
    $('#el').fadeIn();
});
```

So **just move your callback to 3rd param** and everything will work.