# jQuery slider: fadeIn/fadeOut effect not working on 1st slide

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have a simple slideshow of images and use jQuery to fade out one and fade in another, but the effects only work after the first time.

jQuery:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        jQuery('#slider > div:nth-child(2)')
            .fadeOut()
            .next()
            .fadeIn()
            .end()
            .prependTo('#slider');

            jQuery('#slider > div:nth-child(1)')
                .fadeOut()
                .next()
                .fadeIn()
                .end()
                .prependTo('#slider');

    },  5000);
```

CSS:

```
#slider > div:nth-child(1){
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Example code is in link here Please check this will help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819299/jquery-fadeoutfunctionfadein

Answer (score 2):

I think it is to do with your prepending and hiding the first element.  Try this instead (comments in code explaining what is happening):

```js
setInterval(function() {

    // get first and second slides:
    var slide = jQuery('#slider > div:nth-child(1)'),
        nextSlide = slide.next();
  
    // fadeOut the first slide
    slide.fadeOut('slow', function () {
      // when animation is finished fade in second slide and move first slide to second place ready for animation to repeat in reverse 
      nextSlide.fadeIn('slow').after(slide);
    });

}, 5000);
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
}

#slider > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;  // always hide 2nd slide
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test1</div>
  <div>Test2</div>
  <div>Test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to rotate only 1st and 2nd slide

Comment: if I need to add one image?